# Regex to allow numbers and 'All'

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a regex function to allow digits with length of 3 to 8. This could be achieved using `/^[\d]{3,8}$/`

When I want a user input 'All' as well how to implement it?

`/^[\d]{3,8}|(\sAll)$/` is it `?` This doesn't work.

Comment: The `/s` means that user must input ` All` (note the leading whitespace)

Comment: You might mean \s* = 0 or more whitespaces instead of \s means exactly one whitespace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logical OR, `|`, has a low precedence, so your regex:

```
^[\d]{3,8}|(\sAll)$
```

means:

Either match `^[\d]{3,8}` 
or match: `(\sAll)$`

You probably want to group your choices so that both of them need `^` and `$`:

```
^(\d{3,8}|\sAll)$
```

and if you only want to match `All` and not a white space character in front of it, omit the `\s`.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\d{3,8}|All)$
```

- You had a wild `\s`, which looks wrong.
- You don't need to use `[]` around the `\d` as they're equivalent.
- You don't need the `()` around `All` unless you are capturing the group, in which case you should put it around `(\d{3,8}|All)`. You need the latter anyway as pointed out by Bart in the comments.

See it on rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/HX6d7x3qpI

Comment: That matches either `^\d{3,8}` or `All$`. So it matches `123456789` and `fooAll` as well (see my answer).

Comment: @El Ronnoco, just a bit too much tidying, though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\d{3,8}|(All)$/
```

The `\s` was forcing the use of a leading space character..

[Example Here](http://rubular.com/r/QOSw1YwKtP)

**As Tim states** the alternation includes the anchors so `All` with leading spaces will match (as will digits with trailing spaces). To rectify...

```
/(^\d{3,8}$|^All$)/
```

[Example Here](http://rubular.com/r/U7em1hUdmS)

Comment: Watch out - the alternation also includes the anchors!

Comment: Apologies- I've changed the example link and removed the `[]` from around the `\d]`. @Tim good point!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this, instead of complicating your regex:

```
if ( input !== 'All' && input.match ( /^[\d]{3,8}$/ ) === null ) {
  // error
} else {
  // all OK
}
```